# Alternative way to prove that the sum of the square reciprocals is ${\pi^2}/6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

When I learned about how the sum of a series could be divergent and convergent, I decided to try to find the sum of the square reciprocals to no avail. The proof, obviously at not my level as you can tell, was too difficult to understand (what math branch is required because they mentioned something a Riemann Zeta function).

Is there an alternative proof that would yield the result ${\pi^2}/6$ as well without higher math?

Comment: Well can you at least answer my question to what branch of math this is?

Comment: Have a look at the linked post, which contains many proofs... involving many branches of math.

Comment: You can use Fourier analysis.

Comment: The sum is $\pi^2/6$, not $\pi/6$

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed that.